# Trouble With Transform Rotation+IE9/10

Tags: javascript, css, transform

Hoping someone can steer me in the right direction as I've been trying to accomplish this task for a few hours and can't seem to come up with a working cross-browser combination of CSS / Javascript.

Basically, what I am trying to do is a "Card Flip" using CSS and Javascript.
The code works wonderfully in Google Chrome, but I can't seem to get it to work in IE9/10.
Here is a sample [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6829/).

When viewing the same jsfiddle in IE10, you only see the back side of the card and the animation does not work.

Any suggestions?

```
Ignore this - need a code snippet to post the above jsFiddle link.
```

Comment: why put that silly "ignore this" bit? you could just as easily have put a copy if the jsfiddle code (or the relevant part of it if it's too big).

Comment: I figured it would complicate this post when you could simply just click the jsFiddle link to see the entire script in action. I felt it was not needed, although I do understand it's purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **jsFiddle** sample is only working for Chrome (more precisely, webkit browsers).
This is quite logic, as only css -webkit properties are used here.

The Card Flip animation you want to use should also work perfectly for IE10 (And Firefox even not mentioned in your question)

Check out the [W3school page for more details on the 3D Transforms CSS properties](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_3dtransforms.asp) you'll need to use.

Now the problem: **IE9**.

1. IE9 do not provide CSS animations. You'll have to use a fallback
   with    Javascript (jquery animate).
2. IE9 do no provide *rotatey* possibility. BUT, it provides flipX.
   Yes, you will not have the 3D    effect, but you'll still have the
   flip effect.

The IE9 flip property is

```
filter: FlipH;
-ms-filter: "FlipH";
```

Comment: Thank you PIIANTOM. I guess that does make sense! I knew I could perform this animation in IE10 with some additional code (I was looking in the wrong places), but was unsure of what to do for IE9. Your above code will help greatly!  Thanks!